# How to detect double/consecutive character as separator using csv sniffer?

Tags: python, csv, whitespace, separator, sniffer

For instance, the following table uses double whitespaces as a separator for the table values but uses single whitespace before the opening round brackets in the header line. When a csv.Sniffer() is applied to the file, the single whitespace is returned as the delimiter, but not the double whitespace, as expected. How to get the double whitespace as the resulting delimiter?

```
Day (ddd)  N (d)  E (d)  X (m)  Y(s)  Z (c)  S (p)
277  40.52  -36.59  0.11  -0.50  -1.62  30.17
277  40.52  -36.49  0.18  -0.04  -1.66  30.14
277  40.51  -36.39  0.14  -0.07  -1.64  30.15
```

Comment: Do you really need to sniff it? Doubt its possible ...

Comment: The problem is easy to visualize, though probably not implemented in the csv.Sniffer. Not necessarily using the sniffer, how to get that double whitespace as the delimiter instead of the single one?

Comment: The `csv` module does not support multi-character delimiters.

Comment: Thank you Patrick Artner and martineau. Is there another solution to the problem of getting the right delimiter?

Comment: If you know for sure its this format and you can keep the file in memory, you could `data = re.sub(r"  ","|",file.read())` store that in a StringIO and use `csv.reader(iostring, delimiter="|")` to process it.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in a comment the `csv` module doesn't generally support multi-character delimiters. **However** there's a workaround available in this special case because the delimiter happens to be a whitespace character.

```
import csv

filename = "double_whitespace.csv"

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row.
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['277', '40.52', '-36.59', '0.11', '-0.50', '-1.62', '30.17']
['277', '40.52', '-36.49', '0.18', '-0.04', '-1.66', '30.14']
['277', '40.51', '-36.39', '0.14', '-0.07', '-1.64', '30.15']
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner: True, but it could be handled (and there's only one header)…perhaps by doing your `re.sub()` (or an even simpler `str.replace()`) on that one row.

Comment: Thank you. The header line should be kept, otherwise, there is only one separator.

Comment: brenner: See the other answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially cheating - if you *think* you might have `'  '` as delimiter, rewrite them:

```
with open("example.csv","w") as f:
    f.write("""Day (ddd)  N (d)  E (d)  X (m)  Y(s)  Z (c)  S (p)
277  40.52  -36.59  0.11  -0.50  -1.62  30.17
277  40.52  -36.49  0.18  -0.04  -1.66  30.14
277  40.51  -36.39  0.14  -0.07  -1.64  30.15""")

import csv
import io
import re


# keeps the whole file in memory - for big files >2G you'll need to rewrite
# to linebased parsing
stringIO = io.StringIO()
with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        stringIO.write(re.sub("  ","|",line))

stringIO.seek(0)
sn = csv.Sniffer()
dialect = sn.sniff(stringIO.read(1024))

# back to start
stringIO.seek(0)
reader = csv.reader(stringIO, dialect)
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
['Day (ddd)', 'N (d)', 'E (d)', 'X (m)', 'Y(s)', 'Z (c)', 'S (p)']
['277', '40.52', '-36.59', '0.11', '-0.50', '-1.62', '30.17']
['277', '40.52', '-36.49', '0.18', '-0.04', '-1.66', '30.14']
['277', '40.51', '-36.39', '0.14', '-0.07', '-1.64', '30.15']
```

If the file does not contain `"  "` sniffer will work for normal delimiters, if it does, it will replace them with `'|'` (which is hopefully not yet used in your file, you might want to check it and use `';,#'` etc. instead if used).

Comment: Thank you. That solution of "cheating" in memory is promising. I will have to try that. Before that, it should also be possible to detect the double whitespace as a delimiter, before replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution that uses the fact the first argument passed to [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) only has to be somewhat "file-like". This fact means you to could supply an instance of a custom class which changes the double space characters in lines of the file to some other *single* character (such as a comma). If you do this the header row can be handled like any of the others.

Here's what I'm suggesting:

```
import csv

class CSV_Translater:
    """ File-like object that translates characters. """
    def __init__(self, f, old, new):
        self.f, self.old, self.new = f, old, new
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.f).replace(self.old, self.new)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    DELIMITER = ','
    filename = "double_whitespace.csv"

    with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as file:
        translator = CSV_Translater(file, '  ', DELIMITER)
        for row in csv.reader(translator, delimiter=DELIMITER):
            print(row)
```

Output

```
['Day (ddd)', 'N (d)', 'E (d)', 'X (m)', 'Y(s)', 'Z (c)', 'S (p)']
['277', '40.52', '-36.59', '0.11', '-0.50', '-1.62', '30.17']
['277', '40.52', '-36.49', '0.18', '-0.04', '-1.66', '30.14']
['277', '40.51', '-36.39', '0.14', '-0.07', '-1.64', '30.15']
```

Comment: Thank you martineau. The idea of encapsulating the file into an object probably gives me more control of it. I still have to detect that double whitespace first, but the problem of detecting the separator seems solved.

Comment: You're going to have to detect it yourself — because as I said, the csv module doesn't support multi-character delimiters, so the `csv.Sniffer` will never detect them (since they technically aren't CSV files). You could look at the [source code for the `Sniffer`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/csv.py#L159) and perhaps create a custom version of it that handled them.